# Manage the build of multiple libraries in one place

Tags: makefile, cmake, configure, building

Suppose that I have multiple libraries that I can build with `cmake` or with `configure` scripts, there is a tool that can help me with building this libraries such as I can easily manage the rebuilding of this libraries with few modifications like changing compiler's flags ?

I would like to run a sort of automated process a see the feedback about each build + some freedom about building options.

There is a tool like this one beside a conveniently created bash script ?

Answer (score 0):

Make seems like the best tool to use here, but bash script would also work.  You could use a makefile that calls the other makefiles with -f (or switch to the directory with -C ).  Also, you could handle the flags and such within a single makefile with judicious use of variables, targets and recipes.  Realize you can set make variables (and therefore flags) from the command line.  That's about the most I can help without knowing more specifics of your situation.  Good luck!